# XML if statement not calling my function

Tags: javascript, xml

```
if($(xml).find("error") == 'Search short, please enter a longer search item')
{
  showMinChar();
}
```

And in my XML

```
<SearchResults>
<error>Search short, please enter a longer search item</error>
</SearchResults>
```

Is being displayed but the function showMinChar(); is not being called why?

Comment: Without seeing your `showMinChar()` function, no-one can help you debug it. Also, are you seeing / getting any errors in your JS console?

Comment: No Errors - all showMinChar() does is display a error message onto the screen- i know this works because i've tested it

Comment: you missed  $(xml).find("error").text() in your if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use like this**

```
if($(xml).find("error").text() == 'Search short, please enter a longer search item')
{
  showMinChar();
}
```